# Mosfet Analysis

Tags: mosfet, circuit-analysis

The given circuit solution has Vgs = Vds as one of the observation point. However, it didnt provide an explanation on why it is. I did my attempt to understand why by redrawing the circuit to understand it.

1. Was my attempt correct? I'm unsure if the resistor at Vg and Vgs is correct but my analysis wouldn't arrive to the solution of Vgs = Vds without that. Is there an easier way to arrive at the solution? like first glance?
2. The circuit also has an arrow going in with the notation of B? what's that and what does it do?

[image]

Comment: *"However, it didnt provide an explanation on why it is"* - I'm not sure I understand what your question is.  That $V_{DS} = V_{GS}$ is simply a consequence of the fact that the drain and gate are connected together, i.e., $V_{DG} = 0$.  That is, the resistor $R$ is irrelevant.  More formally, and by KVL, $V_{DS} = V_{DG} + V_{GS} = 0 + V_{GS} = V_{GS}$

Answer (score 2):

The "seemingly equivalent circuit " you have re-drawn is wrong. You can't split R into two Rs like that. Anyway you found Vgs = Vds using it, because you took voltage drop across R to be same in both KVL loops. But you can assume it to be same only if Vgs are Vds are given as equal. So its like solving for the value of "x" by substituting the value of "x". If you wanna understand why Vgs and Vds are same , just look at the short between G and D. So the potential is the same at any point on the short. If you still wanna apply KVL and prove it, take these two KVL loops and solve - One outer left loop via R and G and one outer right  via R and D.